# Laravel show number of requests for each meeting

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5

I have these tables: users, meetings, requests:

```
users
id
name

meetings
id
name

requests
id
user_id
meeting_id
accepted
```

each meeting has number of requests from users and request table has accepted column, I want to show a list of user's meetings and number of requests for each meeting
user meetings:

```
requests    meeting name    created_at
10          dummy meeting   10/10/2010
```

Meeting model

```
public function request()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Requests');
    }
```

Requests model

```
public function meeting()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Meeting');
    }
```

How this can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure if the relationship belongsTo is correct.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). You have to define the `foreign_key` and `local_key`

Comment: But I didn't figure out how to display the number of requests for each meeting, I know how to show the number of requests, thanks

Comment: You can do something like `$meeting->request->count()`

Comment: yes, it worked.